# CSS animation for SVG in IE10/IE11

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-transitions

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/cK4SM/2/):

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <style>
    .svg-circle {
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
      transform-origin: 50% 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
      transform: rotateY(0);
    }
    .svg-circle:hover {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
      transform: rotateY(360deg);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
      transition: all 0.7s;
    }
  </style>
  <circle class="svg-circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

It works well in modern browsers. Can I make it works in IE10/IE11? Or I need to use only Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long researching I came to the conclusion the best way for cross-browser support — put image in `<div>` as `background-image` and apply CSS to it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/Lor3zkws/2/)

```css
.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(http://imgh.us/circle_5.svg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
    transform: rotateY(0);
}

    .circle:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
        transition: all 0.7s;
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, is it force on rotating the `<circle/>`?
Because you can easily rotate `<svg></svg>` in all browsers!
If yes, so you are in big trouble because in IE your problem is not only CSS3 support, you going to have some problem with JS, and that's because of `rotateX` or `rotateY`!
And even worst, you going to have some problem with animating it in jQuery!
So I used [`VELOCITY.JS`](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity) to animating it and you can see this [[ SAMPLE ]](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/igFAo) on IE and change `rotateZ` by `rotateY`! (to see rotateY is not working on SVG childs like `path`, `circle`, etc)
It seems you have to change your plan!
Hope to help! And by the way! by puting transition on hover state, you don't have it on hover-back!

Comment: Sorry, I told it not sufficiently detailed. In real situation, I have more complex SVG, and I need to rotate only one part of it on hover on all SVG. I don't want to use any JS, only CSS, if it's possible.
But I think you suggested good way, I'll try to separate SVG on several items. Thanks, I accept your answer.